# How to put back errorchannel message into reply channel?

Tags: spring-integration

I am planning to build a response object when the message comes to errorChannel and put back into the main reply channel of the gateway.

So that my consumer can get always a response object whether it is success or failure.

Is it possible to do that.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just return a response from the error flow and it will go to the caller.

Comment: But it is not happening.  Can you please point out what is wrong in below example..?

https://github.com/manojp1988/spring-integration/blob/master/javadsl/src/main/java/ErrorChannel/ErrorChannelExample.java

Comment: You are returning a `Throwable` (`payload` - which is a `MessagingException`) and the framework will throw that. Since your gateway has a `String` return type, your error flow must return a `String` if you want the caller to get something back.